# Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:12.0.1

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle, onesignal

```
    * What went wrong:
    Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
       > Could not resolve  com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:12.0.1.
         Required by:
             project :app
          > Skipped due to earlier error
       > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:12.0.1.
         Required by:
             project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.3
          > Skipped due to earlier error
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 3m 7s
    Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
    Exited (sigterm)
```

I face this error 1 week please help me everyone my project was build from flutter 1.2.3
and I need to upgrade it because currently it's not working the problem is onesignal and firebase version not fit. Please give me any answer I need to complete this for my company I just in flutter internship

Comment: Could you try changing the network?

Comment: @SalihCan yes I did, but the problem is still exist please help I need to finish it for my Internship work big thanks.